# PHP Page timeout when aborting readfile

Tags: php, readfile

I have an simple php view which looks like this:

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');
readfile($this->image);
exit();
```

In this example `$this->image` is for example `/data/pictures/thumbs/x/xyz.png`.

On an Index HTML I load about 20 products and display their product image with the code above:

```
<img src="views/showimage.php?id=100"/>
```

When I now load the index page with the products, it tooks a short time to load every thumbnail image of the product. If I wait until loading is completed, I can click on each other button on the page and it loads the clicked content.
If I dont wait until the page /images are beeing loaded, I can click on each other button and the browser will run into a timeout. After this I have to clean my cookies and can do it again.

---

### EDIT:

I figured out, that its possible to load the page for 2 times, even though I dont let him complete loading. On the third load, and clicking on navigation before page loads completed, it rans into timeout...

---

This is not an browser problem!

Whos having any idea?
PHP Log is empty.

Comment: Try setting ini value `ignore_user_abort` to false. It will terminate the first script that generates thumbnails if you request another page.

Comment: ini_get('ignore_user_abort') says: ignore_user_abort: 0.

Comment: Then try to wrap calls in time metrics to see which call takes which time. Log these intervals and see the difference between two scenarios.

Comment: what do you mean with wrapping calls in time metrics?

Comment: added some info "edit" to question.

Comment: `$start = microtime(1); foo(); error_log('foo: ' . (microtime(1) - $start)); bar(); error_log('bar: ' . (microtime(1) - $start)); baz(); error_log('baz: ' . (microtime(1) - $start));`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30054/discussion-between-frgtv10-and-maxim-khan-magomedov)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussion we've found the solution.

Root of problem was in excessive data in images. Each image had dimensions of around 40x27 pixels and size more than 1 Mb.

Adding `stripImage()` into part that makes thumbnails stripped away excessive data (which seems to be color profile) and decreased file size to several kb.