# Php-gd png image resize bug

Tags: php, image, png, php-gd

I have a weird bug.

When I create a thumb from a **png** image with transparent background, the thumb filesize is larger (**173,56 KB 500×339 px**) than original (**64,98 KB 600x407 px**).
I think you should see [this code](http://codepad.viper-7.com/fgA5gz) to understand.

Is php-gd library bugged?

Comment: There was a similar problem with `imagick` and solution was to trim excessive data (e.g. EXIF). see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16585584/php-page-timeout-when-aborting-readfile/16589397#16589397)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the GD library is not bugged. Your source image is a 8-bit PNG image (with a color palette). You're saving the resized image as a 32-bit true-color PNG file. That's why it's bigger.